# What should be the threshold for modified z score?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I am trying to find out outliers in my data set. I was previously using z score to calculate that.I was using a 99% confidence interval which is like +/- 2.576 on z score table. However i realized that calculating zscore using median absolute deviation would be better. I have the modified z score based on

```
0.0645*(x- median)/MAD
```

My problem is i am not sure whats a good cutoff in case of modified z score or is it based on kind of data i have?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the type of data you have.  In general, median-based operations lose a little outlier information.  However, the results for sufficiently large data sets should be similar, with the centroid shifted from the mean to the median; in a skewed data set, this will likely give you better results.

As for the cut-off point, here's a starting hint.

Think about the math: traditional Z-scores are based on a root-sum-square computation.  Think about the root(N) factor in this.  How would that affect your 99% point for the median computation, which is a simple linear computation?

Comment: I am not sure of the answer but it feels like you are suggesting the threshold will be dependent on number of record we have?

Comment: If I read your current metric correctly, it's a simple linear computation.  Imagine a data set with scores 1, 2, 3, 4, 1000.  The last is obviously an outlier.  Now insert data 998, 999.  If I understand MAD, you still have the same figure.  However, there's now significant doubt that the top three items are outliers.